# unable to store values in local storage

Tags: json, local-storage

I use the following code for storing values that I get from a php file which connects to a database and returns a json object. I can display these objects using the alert function, so I know the response is present. However, when i check local storage it is empty in the DOM for firebug.

```
$.getJSON("sessionstore.php", {id: $( "#customer option:selected" ).text()}, function(data){
        $.each(data,function(index,item) 
        {
          localStorage.setItem('username', item.EmpName);
          localStorage.setItem('usermail', item.EmpMail);
          localStorage.setItem('repsupervisor', item.RepSupervisor);
          localStorage.setItem('supmail', item.SupMail);
          localStorage.setItem('issup', item.IsSupervisor);
        });    
        });

            window.open("formselect.html","_self");
```

I am not sure if it is due to opening a new window.

Regards

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle which replicates the issue? Is the new window open for the same domain?

Comment: It is the window opening. That is executed after the request to sessionstore.php is sent, but before the result is processed. 

Also, you're looping over an array of items, but using the same keys in localstorage. You'll only ever get one set in there.